# An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with WordPress.org

Tags: themes

I installed wordpress through .zip file on ubuntu. Once I finished configuring the `wp-config.php`, I created an account in wordpress and opened it through my localhost. When I tried to add new themes it is showing me an error message like this

> An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with WordPress.org or this server’s configuration. If you continue to have problems, please try the support forums.

1. I tried to open it by using a proxy and two other connections but didn't work.
2. I opened it in Chrome and Firefox. No use.
3. I re-installed wordpress after clearing the obsolete files and folders. Still nothing happened.
4. I gave full access to read write and execute to the wordpress folder in my var/www folder and files in wordpress. No use
5. When I tried with direct connection without any proxy it is working fine.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

This error indicates that your WP installation couldn't perform a network request to remote API. Either because it's prevented from doing so in general (by firewall for example) or core couldn't correctly determine and/or use available HTTP transport.

[Core Control](https://wordpress.org/plugins/core-control/) plugin is a good starting point to log and troubleshoot such network errors.

Comment: that plugin needs ftp connection, i dont have any username and password for that

Comment: @Dragonslayer FTP conenction for what? You can just download zip file and unapck into your installation since you cannot install via admin