# Getting no Error Log File saved to my local directory, and no debug info displayed in the web browser

Tags: errors, linux

I have installed WordPress on my Ubuntu Server 20.04 VM (host machine runs Linux Mint 19).  I've able to view wp-admin and the sample website without issue.  I'm using Firefox to access wp-admin, the browser is up to date, and the browser clears the cache/history each time I close it.

When I click **Themes** in wp-admin, the page opens just fine.  But when I click **Add New**, a progress bar keeps spinning, and then I get the following message:

> An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with WordPress.org or this server’s configuration.

I found [another StackExchange post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/177637/no-error-log-file-no-debug-info) that suggests adding some lines to the **wp-config.php** file, so that I could debug my issue.  I've added these lines, saved the file, ran `sudo service apache2 restart` for good measure, closed the browser, then reopened it.  I didn't get any log info posted in the browser, and I don't see any log files saved in the **wp-content** directory.

I also found [another StackExchange post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/144940/an-unexpected-error-occurred-something-may-be-wrong-with-wordpress-org) that suggested I install the [Core Control](https://wordpress.org/plugins/core-control/) plugin.  But when I go to **Add Plugins** in wp-admin, I get the same error message.

So I can't add a new WordPress theme, and I can't debug the issue using WordPress tools either.

Please know I'm a beginning engineer, with light experience with html/css, python, and bash.  I'd appreciate any help I'm able to get.  Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this is so much a WP issue as it is may be a server config issue... if you added the lines of code to `wp-config.php` then you should get error logs.  But if you're not it could be any number of things, including how the permissions for your VM are configured.  I don't know if server configuration for WP is on or off topic though.

Answer (score 0):

I may have posted my question too soon!

I found [another web page](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360005045734-Unable-to-find-any-theme-or-add-plugins-in-WordPress-An-unexpected-error-occurred-Something-may-be-wrong-with-WordPress-org-or-this-server-s-configuration) that suggested adding `198.143.164.251 api.wordpress.org` to `/etc/hosts`.

I did that, and now I can at add themes and plugins!  And since WordPress isn't giving me any errors now, I can't replicate the issues with the debugger.

So it looks like I've answered my own question.  Hopefully others can find my post useful.